Freeradius: How to enable 2fa for EAP-TTLS/PAP
Our company uses Freeradius to authenticate users to the WiFi network via wpa2-enterprise. However a new policy wants that we use two factor authentication in combination with the standard username and password.
Currently we use EAP-TTLS/PAP to authenticate users. We use LDAP as backend. Because our LDAP won't provide Freeradius with clear passwords it is not possible to use MS-CHAP v2 or other encryption techniques besides EAP-TTLS/PAP and Windows cannot use PAP only for WiFi authentication.
I started with the DUO auth proxy "auto" (https://duo.com/docs/authproxy-reference#radius-auto) which is a RADIUS proxy. The access points will directly contact DUO auth proxy and DUO auth proxy forwards the request to Freeradius. When Freeradius sends Access-Accept, DUO auth proxy will send a push message to the phone. When the push message is acknowledged DUO auth proxy will send Access-Accept to the Access point. However this won't work, because the access point will timeout in 5 seconds and this timeout is not configurable.
Second I used the DUO auth proxy "challenge" (https://duo.com/docs/authproxy-reference#radius-challenge). Same concept as above, but instead of a push notification DUO auth proxy will send Access-Challenge to the access point and the user must provide the OTP. This looked promising, but DUO auth proxy only works when the access point sends the password in clear text which is not the case, because it is using EAP-TTLS/PAP.
Third I tried to implement the Access-Challenge myself in the inner-tunnel site. As reference I used the 'site' Challenge located in site-available": https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/master/raddb/sites-available/challenge. However this will give me the same errors as https://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2022-August/102247.html. In the thread they mentioned that EAP-TTLS/PAP won't accept interactive Access-Challenge responses. So this is also not an option.
Are there other ways how I can implement 2fa for wpa2-enterprise?
